# XAMPP , PROFTPD problems

Tags: mysql, xampp, proftpd

i have installed XAMPP on my macOS Mojave. When im running this command 'sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start'

i get following errors:

Starting XAMPP for Mac OS X 7.2.10-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
Contents of "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/proftpd/start.err":
Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[4057]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local'
Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[4057]: error: no valid servers configured
Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[4057]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'

My proftpd.conf file:

```
# This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to 
# 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
# and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
# "daemon" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

ServerName          "ProFTPD"
ServerType          standalone
DefaultServer           on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21
# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask               022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User daemon
Group      admin

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*>
  AllowOverwrite        on
</Directory>

# only for the web servers content
DefaultRoot /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs

<Limit SITE_CHMOD>                                                                                                                                                         
  DenyAll                                                                                                                                                                  
</Limit>  

# daemon gets the password "xampp"
UserPassword daemon 2TgxE8g184G9c

# daemon is no normal user so we have to allow users with no real shell
RequireValidShell off

# daemon may be in /etc/ftpusers so we also have to ignore this file
#to login with "OSX Users"
AuthPAM on
AuthPAMConfig ftpd
UseFtpUsers off
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanx

Comment: please add /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf contents to the question.

Comment: Updated the question now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try to add :

```
127.0.0.1  Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local
```

to your `/etc/hosts` file and try again

Comment: Wow finally, thanks! But why is it Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local and not 'localhost' ??

Comment: because most of the services refer to the result of `hostname` command and `Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local`  is your computer (host) name

Comment: ah ok thanx. Could u tell me how i can give a access to a file like this trough terminal? -> -rw-r--r--@ , i would be glad if u could help me with that =)

Comment: this is a different issue, please create another SO question with the "sharing" problem or check other questions like this. i.e: https://superuser.com/questions/1110783/how-can-i-access-localhost-using-xampp-with-filezilla-on-mac-os-x

Comment: To find your Mac hostname just enter "hostname" into the terminal

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, you should try the following steps:

Check the ProFTPD configuration file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf) and make sure that the "DefaultRoot" directory exists and is set to a valid path.
Check the permissions on the directory set in the "DefaultRoot" directive to ensure that the user running ProFTPD (daemon in this case) has read and execute access.
Make sure that the "User" and "Group" directives in the configuration file are set to valid values, and that the user running ProFTPD has permission to access the specified directories.
If the issue persists, you may try to reinstall XAMPP or consult the XAMPP support documentation for further troubleshooting guidance.
Note: The warning message "unable to determine IP address of 'Mudasars-MacBook-Pro.local'" might be due to a DNS resolution issue, but it doesn't seem to be directly related to the failure of ProFTPD starting.